# npm run start выдает ошибку

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

Все было хорошо до того момента, пока я не запустил `$ npm audit fix --force`
После этого, когда я пытаюсь ввести `$ npm run start` мне выдает ошибку

```
~/Desktop/callreport/server$ npm run start

> call-report@0.0.1 start

Invalid command: start
See --help for a list of available commands.
```

и `npm --help` выдет следуещее:

```
~/Desktop/callreport/server$ npm --help
npm <command>

Usage:

npm install        install all the dependencies in your project
npm install <foo>  add the <foo> dependency to your project
npm test           run this project's tests
npm run <foo>      run the script named <foo>
npm <command> -h   quick help on <command>
npm -l             display usage info for all commands
npm help <term>    search for help on <term>
npm help npm       more involved overview

All commands:

    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, cache, ci, completion,
    config, dedupe, deprecate, diff, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, exec, explain, explore, find-dupes, fund, get, help,
    hook, init, install, install-ci-test, install-test, link,
    ll, login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping,
    pkg, prefix, profile, prune, publish, rebuild, repo,
    restart, root, run-script, search, set, set-script,
    shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, team, test, token,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, update, version, view, whoami

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /home/bluepuper/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key=value

More configuration info: npm help config
Configuration fields: npm help 7 config

npm@8.6.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

(`package.json` файл в порядке, без понятия, что вообще случилось)

UPDT:
Понял, что ошибку выдает не сам npm, а nestjs/cli
Через npm я запускаю такой скрипт `"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nest start"` а уже сам `nestjs` выдает ошибку `Invalid command "start"`

Comment: точно package.json в порядке? что там в "scripts"?

Comment: @vanesicks обновил вопрос!)